# require is not a function by JsonWebToken

Tags: node.js, json-web-token

I get when using the following codes

```
 var jwt = require ("JsonWebToken");
 var token = jwt.sign ({foo: 'bar'}, 'shhhhh');
```

this error message ***"require is not a function"***

I hope you can help me.

Regards Christian

Comment: You need to define **require** function which you are calling here  `var jwt = require ("JsonWebToken");`

Comment: How are you executing this code? On the command line via `node foo.js`? Or if you're on Windows, are you merely double-clicking on the javascript file?

Comment: @GeekyNinja No, node already defines `require()` as part of its module loading mechanism and (along with other variables) is passed to all modules, so it *should* already be available.